# Eclipse: How to programmatically get Launching preferences

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

The plugin does not have an activator. It needs to access the Eclipse IDE's preference values defined on Window -> Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Launching page.

How to do it programmatically?

Comment: Not sure why you got a downvote, seems a legit question to me. The plug-in does have an activator, but it is internal org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.

Comment: thank you for help on the activator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like:

```java
IPreferenceStore store = new ScopedPreferenceStore(InstanceScope.INSTANCE, IDebugUIConstants.PLUGIN_ID);

store.getBoolean(IDebugUIConstants.PREF_BUILD_BEFORE_LAUNCH);

... other preferences listed in IDebugUIConstants
```

not all the preferences on the launching page are listed in `IDebugUIConstants`. The others are considered internal.